# GPS position out of map depending on CRS in QField

Tags: qfield

I have a QGIS project with CRS `CH1903+ / LV95 (EPSG:2056)`. When opening the project in QField, the GPS-position is way out of the map.

When changing the same project to `WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)` and opening it in QField, I get precise GPS-position.

What can I do that QField shows the correct position in my origin-CRS?

I’m sure that both, the project and the layers are in the same CRS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After uninstalling and installing the newest QField version, it shows the correct position again. I don’t know what happened.

It worked for sure with older QField versions, like 2.1.4 for sure. Now with the new installed version 2.8.2 it works again. I don’t know if a version in between had a bug or something happened with the settings on my phone.